# lowercased variables in pattern matching

Tags: scala

This code works OK:

```
val StringManifest = manifest[String]
val IntManifest = manifest[Int]

def check[T: Manifest] = manifest[T] match {
    case StringManifest => "string"
    case IntManifest => "int"
    case _ => "something else"
}
```

But if we lowercase the first letter of the variables:

```
val stringManifest = manifest[String]
val intManifest = manifest[Int]

def check[T: Manifest] = manifest[T] match {
    case stringManifest => "string"
    case intManifest => "int"
    case _ => "something else"
}
```

we will get "unreachable code" error.

What are the reasons of this behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In scala's pattern matching, lowercase is used for variables that should be *bound* by the matcher.  Uppercase variables or backticks are used for existing variable that should be *used* by the matcher.

Try this instead:

```
def check[T: Manifest] = manifest[T] match {
  case `stringManifest` => "string"
  case `intManifest` => "int"
  case _ => "something else"
}
```

The reason you're getting the "Unreachable code" error is that, in your code, `stringManifest` is a variable that will always bind to whatever `manifest` is.  Since it will always bind, that case will always be used, and the `intManifest` and `_` cases will never be used.

Here's a short demonstration showing the behavior

```
val a = 1
val A = 3
List(1,2,3).foreach {
  case `a` => println("matched a")
  case A => println("matched A")
  case a => println("found " + a)
}
```

This yields:

```
matched a
found 2
matched A
```