# GraphX-Spark: error graph.vertices.filter

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I am new in scala and spark-graphx.
This is a method that I've written to extract the vertex that has min score value

```
def getMinScoreVertex(graph: Graph[(Int,Float,Float,Float,String),Float]):Float={
var minValue:Float=Float.PositiveInfinity
var LowestScoreValue=graph.vertices.filter { case (id,(_,_,_,Score,_)) => Score < minValue}
 return LowestScoreValue  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(15, 62) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
 required: (org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, (Int, Float, Float, Float, String))
    (which expands to)  (Long, (Int, Float, Float, Float, String))
    var LowestScoreValue=graph.vertices.filter { case (_,_,_,Score,_) => Score < minValue}
Error:(15, 69) not found: value Score
    var LowestScoreValue=graph.vertices.filter { case (_,_,_,Score,_) => Score < minValue}
Error:(15, 82) not found: value Score
    var LowestScoreValue=graph.vertices.filter { case (_,_,_,Score,_) => Score < minValue}
```

Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: Use `case` correctly. `case (_,_,_,s: Score,_) => s < minValue`

Comment: Always the same error

Comment: My mistake. I post answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the commend I made a mistake, thinking Score is type. Most of time if you do pattern matching, it's safe to use lower-case letters. ([lowercased variables in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714409/lowercased-variables-in-pattern-matching))

```
val filterResult = graph.vertices.filter {
    case (_, (_, _, _, score, _)) => score < minValue
}
```

This will not give compilation error.

One more thing is `filter` is not the right choice to select the minimum choice. It'll just filter VertexRDD which has score less than minValue and will return list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Always the same compilation error.

Comment: Type mismatch expected (graphx.VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float,String))=>Boolean , actual: (graphx.VertexId,(Int,Float,Float,Float,String))=>Any

Comment: @imen My worksheet is clean. Is it at `filterResult`?

Comment: @imen nice :) Could you choose the answer please if I may?